# Adding a promise to sequence if condition is met

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a Promise, *`Promise A`*, which 'checks' some condition asynchronously. It is always resolved (no rejection), so only `then` is necessary. The `resolve` is either true or false (the aforementioned condition).

If the condition is not met (`resolve(false)`) in the first promise, a second promise, *`Final Promise`* is then executed. However, if the initial condition was met (`resolve(true)`), an additional promise is executed 'between the two': *`Promise B`*.

[image: Diagram of what I'm saying]

Because *`Final Promise`* produces two callbacks (`then` and `catch`), **I am trying to avoid code duplication**. This is what I'm using, which works, but the final callbacks are duplicated.

```
promiseA().then((condition) => {
    if (condition) {
        promiseB().then(finalPromise().then(() => {
            console.log('final promise success');
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('final promise failure');
        }));
    } else {
        finalPromise().then(() => {
            console.log('final promise success');
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log('final promise failure');
        });
    }
});
```

I *tried* the following, but it doesn't work: *`Final Promise`* is being executed before *`Promise B`*.

```
promiseA().then((condition) => {
    if (condition) {
        return promiseB();
    }
}).then(finalPromise().then(() => {
    console.log('final promise success');
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('final promise failure');
}));
```

Additionally, I tried using the following, but then *`Final Promise`* wouldn't be executed after *`Promise B`*:

```
promiseA().then((condition) => {
    if (condition) {
        return promiseB();
    }
}).then(finalPromise).then(() => {
    console.log('final promise success');
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('final promise failure');
});
```

I'm guessing I could store everything that is inside the `else` branch (in the first snippet) into a variable and use it for both cases. I'm wondering if there's a solution built into the Promise API.

Comment: .then expects a function, not a promise, as an argument ... this `.then(finalPromise().then` returns a promise ... `}).then(finalPromise).then(` looks OK, but without seeing code for `finalPromise` that's a guess

Comment: note: the only reason `Final Promise wouldn't be executed after Promise B` in the last code example is if `promiseB` rejects

Comment: @JaromandaX `finalPromise` is a function that returns a Promise, similarly to the other promises (`promiseA()` returns Promise, etc.). Sorry if that wasn't clear from the Q

Comment: well, then I can't see why you'd say `Final Promise wouldn't be executed after Promise B` - it definitely would

Comment: @JaromandaX In the third snippet, if the condition is true, Promise B alone is executed (and the final one isn't). If it was false, the final promise alone is executed. This isn't what I'm trying to do, but that's what the snippet does on my end.

Comment: `}).then(finalPromise().then(() => {` is just WRONG.  As others have said, you're passing a promise to `.then()` not a function.  You don't seem to understand this yet.  You need `}).then(() => finalPromise.then(...))`.

Comment: you're doing something wrong in that case. If promiseA, promiseB and finalPromise all return a Promise, then the code should work - here's a fiddle based on your 3rd code https://jsfiddle.net/t3qf4d0n/ ... and here's code that tests both true and false results from promiseA - https://jsfiddle.net/t3qf4d0n/1/

Comment: @jfriend00 - `finalPromise.then` - I assumed finalPromis was a **function**, surely OP's final code would work if so

Comment: @JaromandaX - `finalPromise().then()` is a promise, not a function unless this a completely non-standard `.then()` that returns a function which seems very unlikely.

Comment: @JaromandaX You were right, the snippet was correct. It was due to a mistake in Promise B. I have submitted an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 - sorry, I was referring to the THIRD code snippet :p

Comment: @JaromandaX - This is just an overall bad question, besides being confusing and the wrong assertions about what is happening, the eventual problem is not even in code that's included here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The **third snippet** works, but I needed to 'manually' resolve *Promise B* to continue the chain (I learned something new!).

```
function promiseB() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('Promise B execution');
        resolve(); // adding this solved it
    });
}
```

The queue snippet:

```
promiseA().then((condition) => {
    if (condition) {
        return promiseB();
    }
}).then(finalPromise).then(() => {
    console.log('final promise success');
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('final promise failure');
});
```

Comment: well, yes, a promise has to resolve somehow, otherwise it remains pending

Comment: Yep, I'm new to promises :) I assumed that it would resolve itself if I did nothing... *somehow*...